# Setting up new framework-based projects and using LESS

Tags: html, css, less, zurb-foundation

So I'm trying to set up an environment where I can generate a new project and minimize the customization/complexity involved in setting up that new project.  I'm using Structurer Pro (from nettuts+) to build the fileset, and this is an awesome thing.  I've got github for MAC set up, allowing me to grab the latest Foundation framework files and put them in to the current project.

Now, I'm trying to incorporate LESS into the process also.  However, Foundation's css files aren't currently set up with LESS, which means I have 2 options...(1) take a current version and LESS-ize them, then use those customized files to create new projects. (2) don't use LESS...

The other problem I have is, there seem to be quite a few compilers for LESS (simpLESS, CodeKit, LESS, compass), but none of them combine css files!  So if I set up 10 LESS files (e.g. IE.less, mobile.less, grid.less, typography.less etc), and have the variables in them, I really don't want 10 css files as the output.  I really want 1 compiled css file as the output.  I know I can do this manually, or even through Clean css or any of the 30 other sites out there...

But is there one 'thing' out there that will let me use the latest files to create a project framework, customize it by applying a color swatch set to a series of variables (LESS), then compile & combine the resulting CSS for actual implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foundation ended up moving to SCSS in version 3, so this became kind of a moot point...

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer some of your questions:

1. Rename Foundation's .css files to .less and put in your /less/ directory.

   - Any .css file is a valid .less file (not vice versa though)
   - You don't have to convert this CSS to LESS, do so only for things you're going to be modifying, and save some time ;)
2. In your master.less file import these files with @import 'foundation-file';

   - re: how to combine css/less files :)
3. Compile only the master.less and include it in your HTML

   - master.less is your assumed **MAIN** stylesheet which may actually contain only @import statements, for me it's easier to manage everything this way (and where the combination happens). it will compile to master.css which you then use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what css foundation includes, if it's a reset.css or something similar I would just leave it and not less-ize it. You would have two css files: one reset.css and one styles.css (the latter of which would be compiled from less files).

You could then add your own setup including a style.less which @imports the various components, if you make this generic enough you can reuse it throughout various projects.

The lessc compiler does handle the @imports of various files and combines them into one file: I have styles.less which @imports base.less components.less etc. I just compile the styles.less to styles.css and it handles the rest:

```
lessc styles.less styles.css
```

See: https://gist.github.com/1480684